# UIWebView Rotation and Background Color

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I've run into an interesting situation with a UIWebView. In Interface Builder, I set all four constraints to equal the margins and filled the webview with content. It works exactly as you'd expect.

An issue occurs when I rotate the webview. The webview rotates but in doing so, it reveals an grey background color. This isn't a color that I've set. In fact, I set the parent's view to have a black background color to match the webview content.

[image]

Here are my constraints for reference:

[image]

I'd appreciate any guidance on how to make my webview will the entire border or at least, manually change the grey color. Much thanks!

Note: This only occurs in the simulator. I haven't tried this on a device yet.

Answer (score 0):

Ack ... it was the background view that was the culprit. The simulator didn't pick up my color changes. I never did a clean on them. I tested today and was able to change the grey color to the one of my choosing.